# Why is my Cloudflare AppService failing to Oauth?

Tags: cloudflare-apps

I’m having an issue completing the OAuth process for our Cloudflare app that's in development.

I've been following the documentation here https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/developer/docs/webhooks/managing-accounts and I'm stuck in #10 in the list, which is #9 in the flow chart.

My server is returning the following

```
content-type: application/json
response
{
"token": “eXamPleTokeEn12",
"type": "Bearer",
"expiration": "2020-08-18T00:13:37.109Z"
}
```

Which is what the documentation is telling me to do, so I don’t understand why it’s not working.

If you could help me figure this out so I can submit our app for certification that would be great.

Here's the error I'm getting:

> A communication error occurred while contacting this app’s web
> service. Some functionality may not work correctly. While some
> communication issues automatically resolve themselves, we’ve notified
> the app developer that this has error occured. Please contact us if
> you continue to see this message.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thank you!